ImportError: Failed to load GLFW3 shared library
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "esp.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "imgui\integrations\glfw.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 419, in exec_module
  File "glfw\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
ImportError: Failed to load GLFW3 shared library.

После того как прогнал через auto-py-to-exe начала вылезать ошибка. Через vscode запускается без проблем. В чем может быть проблема?
